# reponsive image in section

Tags: css, image

how can I add to section responsive background image 100% height? Now I don't have any image.

```
    <section class="takecare">

    </section>

takecare{
  background-image: url("images/craft.jpg");
  height: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a typo mistake.
Your css should look like

```
.takecare{ background-image: url("images/craft.jpg"); height: 100%; background-position: center; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: cover; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to add the element 'section' before the .takecare in case you want to add some things in this section and customize them without adding a ton of classes and id for nothing.

```
section.takecare{
  background-image: url("images/craft.jpg");
  height: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Btw the answer of Amab is good, this is just some recommendation.

Greetings.

Answer (score 0):

`height: 100%` doesn't work with if parent node doesn't have a fixed height. Try to add a fixed `height` like:

```css
.takecare{
  background-image: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/34/70_Years_Porsche_Sports_Car%2C_Berlin_%281X7A3888%29.jpg");
  height: 200px;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<section class="takecare"></section>
```